# How to configure Google Play Service to be able to log in?

Tags: android

I read a lot of guides and questions here but couldn't manage to sign in properly...
I get this errors:

```
    09-17 10:56:52.359  12355-12433/? E/Volley﹕ [155507] tm.a: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/games/v1/players/112114949070942314658?language=en_US
09-17 10:56:53.064  12355-12781/? E/SignInIntentService﹕ Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.

09-17 10:56:53.304  12552-12552/? E/LoadSelfFragment﹕ Unable to sign in - application does not have a registered client ID
```

I found Q about SH1 and client ID and app ID and did all of that but still nothing.

what do  I do wrong?